# How to insert custom field values in civicrm?

Tags: php, custom-fields, civicrm

Hello friends I created some custom fields for contacts. How can I insert values to that custom fields. I tried to pass the custom values with params. but its not inserting. how to insert that values. 
Kindly help me.

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried?

Comment: I created the contact using "civicrm_contact_create($params)" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Define input parms for the contact and initial primary location

```
$params = array(
                'first_name'    => 'Dan',
                'custom_{put your custom filed id here}' => "custom field value1",
                'custom_{put your custom filed id here}' => "custom field value2"
                );
$contact =&civicrm_contact_create( $params );
print_r($contact);
```

Like this way we can insert value to custom fields